# Finding Rotation Angles between 3d points

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation

I am writing a program that will draw a solid along the curve of a spline. I am using visual studio 2005, and writing in C++ for OpenGL. I'm using FLTK to open my windows (fast and light toolkit).

I currently have an algorithm that will draw a Cardinal Cubic Spline, given a set of control points, by breaking the intervals between the points up into subintervals and drawing linesegments between these sub points. The number of subintervals is variable.

The line drawing code works wonderfully, and basically works as follows: I generate a set of points along the spline curve using the spline equation and store them in an array (as a special datastructure called Pnt3f, where the coordinates are 3 floats and there are some handy functions such as distance, length, dot and crossproduct). Then i have a single loop that iterates through the array of points and draws them as so:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for(pt = 0; pt<=numsubsegements ; ++pt) {
    glVertex3fv(pt.v());
}
glEnd();
```

As stated, this code works great. Now what i want to do is, instead of drawing a line, I want to extrude a solid. My current exploration is using a 'cylinder' quadric to create a tube along the line. This is a bit trickier, as I have to orient openGL in the direction i want to draw the cylinder. My idea is to do this:

Psuedocode:

```
Push the current matrix,
translate to the first control point
rotate to face the next point
draw a cylinder (length = distance between the points)
Pop the matrix
repeat
```

My problem is getting the angles between the points. I only need yaw and pitch, roll isnt important. I know take the arc-cosine of the dot product of the two points divided by the magnitude of both points, will return the angle between them, but this is not something i can feed to OpenGL to rotate with. I've tried doing this in 2d, using the XZ plane to get x rotation, and making the points vectors from the origin, but it does not return the correct angle.

My current approach is much simpler. For each plane of rotation (X and Y), find the angle by:

arc-cosine( (difference in 'x' values)/distance between the points)

the 'x' value depends on how your set your plane up, though for my calculations I always use world x.

Barring a few issues of it making it draw in the correct quadrant that I havent worked out yet, I want to get advice to see if this was a good implementation, or to see if someone knew a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in forming two vectors from the three points in two adjacent line segments and then using the arccosine of the dot product to get the angle between them. To make use of this angle you need to determine the axis around which the rotation should occur. Take the cross product of the same two vectors to get this axis. You can then [build a transformation matrix](http://web.archive.org/web/20041029003853/http:/www.j3d.org/matrix_faq/matrfaq_latest.html#Q38) using this axis-angle or pass it as parameters to [glRotate](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml).

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:
first of all, this:

```
for(pt = 0; pt<=numsubsegements ; ++pt) {
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex3fv(pt.v());
}
glEnd();
```

is not a good way to draw anything. You MUST have one glEnd() for every single glBegin(). you probably want to get the glBegin() out of the loop. the fact that this works is pure luck.

second thing

> My current exploration is using a
>   'cylinder' quadric to create a tube
>   along the line

**This will not work as you expect.** the 'cylinder' quadric has a flat top base and a flat bottom base. Even if you success in making the correct rotations according to the spline the edges of the flat tops are going to pop out of the volume of your intended tube and it will not be smooth. You can try it in 2D with just a pen and a paper. Try to draw a smooth tube using only shorter tubes with a flat bases. This is impossible.

Third, to your actual question, The definitive tool for such rotations are [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions). Its a bit complex to explain in this scope but you can find plentyful information anywhere you look.
If you'd have used QT instead of FLTK you could have also used [libQGLViewer](http://www.libqglviewer.com/). It has an integrated Quaternion class which would save you the implementation. If you still have a choice I strongly recommend moving to QT.

Comment: the glBegin was a typo. Thank you for catching that. I have corrected it.

Comment: unfortunatley, this is a for a class which requires FLTK.

Do you know how you would actually draw the tube? I'm guessing i'm going to have to code the quadric self as a sort of retangular prism?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [`gluLookAt`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/glu/lookat.html)? Put your control point as the eye point, the next point as the reference point, and make the up vector perpendicular to the difference between the two.